# Rmarkdown and xelatex minipages don't work on linux/ubuntu but work on windows

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, xelatex

I have a basic report in Rmarkdown

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
     latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: left=2cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=0cm
fontsize: 12pt

params:
  A: test
  B: test2
  C: test3

header-includes:
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{fontspec}
---


\begin{minipage}{2in}
Personal-Nr. `r params$A`
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{1in}
`r params$B`
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-\parskip}

\begin{minipage}{2in}
AHV-Nr. `r params$A`
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{1in}
`r params$B`
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-\parskip}

\begin{minipage}{2in}
Eintritt: `r params$A`
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{1in}
`r params$B`
\end{minipage}

\vspace{-\parskip}

\
\

\large
**TITLE**
\normalsize
```

When I run this on my Windows + Rstudio + R 4.0
I see this

[image]

And this is how it looks on my Ubuntu Linux server (with installed xelatex)

[image]

I am wondering why these commands (minipages and also \large) seem to be ignored on linux?
Am I missing a header or a package?